# Integral vanishing over every half space implies that $f =0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, fourier-transform

In Chapter 13 of the book "Lebesgue Integration on Euclidean Spaces" by Frank Jones, Problem 32 asks the reader to prove that if a function $f \in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is such that 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_H f(x) \ dx =0 
\end{eqnarray*} 
for every Half Space $H$, where a Half Space is defined as 
\begin{eqnarray*}
H = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^n \ | \ x \cdot \xi \leq c \}
\end{eqnarray*}
for some fixed $\xi \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f =0$ a.e.

The book gave a hint for the problem, and it goes like this ($\hat{f}$ denotes Fourier Transform):

"You should try to prove that $\hat{f}=0$, then apply the Fourier Inversion Theorem. Denote $x^{\prime} = (x_1,\ldots,x_{n-1})$. Why does
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int^c_{-\infty} dx_n \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} f(x) \ dx^{\prime} =0
\end{eqnarray*}
for every $c$? Why does this imply 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} f(x^{\prime},x_n) \ dx^{\prime}=0
\end{eqnarray*}
for a.e. $x_n\in\mathbb{R}$? Why does this imply 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} f(x) e^{-itx_n}\ dx=0
\end{eqnarray*}
for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$?"

I have no problem with the hint, but I have no idea how to proceed from here. The statement only implies that $\hat{f}(x)=0$ for every $x$ of the form $(0,\ldots,t,\ldots,0)$. From here, how can I prove that $\hat{f}(x) =0$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$? Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Change of coordinates to a rotated ON-system such that $x = (0, \ldots, t, \ldots, 0)$ in the new coordinates?

Comment: I have tried that,  but a shift in coordinates of the fourier transform results in a phase shift of the original function. I have no idea how to prove that $\int_H f(x) e^{-itx_n} \ dx =0$ for every half space H.

Answer (score 0):

For $c \in \mathbb R$ and $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$, let $H(c,\xi) = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid x \cdot \xi \leq c \}.$

Fix $\xi \in \mathbb R^n$. We can then write
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{|\xi|} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{\partial H(c,\xi)} f(x' + t \xi) \, dx' \, dt.$$
and
$$\int_{H(c,\xi)} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{|\xi|} \int_{-\infty}^{c} \int_{\partial H(c,\xi)} f(x' + t \xi) \, dx' \, dt.$$

Since $\int_{H(c,\xi)} f(x) \, dx = 0$ for all $c$ we have
$$0 = \frac{d}{dc} \int_{H(c,\xi)} f(x) \, dx = \frac{1}{|\xi|} \int_{\partial H(c,\xi)} f(x' + c\xi) \, dx'$$
for a.e. $c \in \mathbb R.$

Therefore we have
$$e^{-i t |\xi|^2} \int_{\partial H(c,\xi)} f(x' + c \xi) \, dx = 0$$
and thus
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-i t |\xi|^2} \int_{\partial H(c,\xi)} f(x' + c \xi) \, dx \, dt = 0.$$

Since $x = x' + c \xi$ gives $\xi \cdot x = c |\xi|^2$, this can be written as
$$\int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x) \, e^{-i \xi \cdot x} \, dx = 0.$$

Now, $\xi$ was arbitrary. Thus the last equation is valid for all $\xi$ so
$$\hat f(\xi) = 0$$
and the Fourier inversion formula gives us $f(x) = 0$ for a.e. $x \in \mathbb R^n.$